# Environment management in R functions

Tags: r, environment-variables

I am using two functions:

```
csvExport <- function(data, path = "", enc = 'utf8'){
    filename <- paste(data, "csv", sep=".")
    if (path == ""){
      name <- filename
    } else {
      name <- paste(path, '/', filename, sep="")
    }
    x <- get(data) # get the object
    con <- file(name, encoding = enc)
    write.csv2(x, file = con, row.names=FALSE, quote = TRUE)
  }  
}
```

and

```
listExport <- function(myList){
  for(n in names(myList)){
    assign(n, myList[[n]])
    csvExport(n)
  }
}
```

For testing purposes:

```
test <- function(){
  a <- data.frame(x = c(1,2,3,4,5), y = c(5,4,3,2,1))
  b <- data.frame(x = c(1,2,3,4,5), y = c(5,4,3,2,1))
  myList <- list(a1 = a, b1 = b)
  listExport(myList)
}
```

Now, a call to `test()` gives an "Object a1 not found" error. I assume this is some kind of messed up environment since the error occurs in the line

```
x <- get(data)
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: What are you really trying to do? A lot of this looks unnecessary.

Comment: I have functions that create lists with results from analysis. These results are data frames. I like to export each data frame as a cvs file for further processing using the above functions.

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of options. One is to make your `csvExport` function accept a data.frame instead of a name of a data.frame and do `csvExport(get(n))` inside of `listExport`, which will be in the correct environment I believe, unless assign defaults to global, which I don't think it does. Or just drop the whole `get` thing and pass `myList[[n]]` directly to `csvExport`